# SQL queries about multiple related tags and items relationships

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tagging

I've searched in SO for some of the following queries, but I can't find something that match my search, and I'm a little bit lost between `IN`, `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` to write them.

The current database relationships
[image]

**1. Get the items by tags**

`TAG.url` are strings got from a `$_GET`, so not INT ids.

For example, with the url `mydomain/items/tag1+tag2/`, we'll have the following requests.

For one tag that was easy but for two or more, the following doesn't seems to work in mySQL :

```
SELECT 
    ITEM.id AS 'item_id',
    ITEM.title AS 'item_title',
    ITEM.content AS 'item_content'
  FROM ITEM, ITEM_TAG, TAG
WHERE
  (ITEM.id=ITEM_TAG.id_item AND TAG.id=ITEM_TAG.id_dtag AND TAG.url='tag1')
AND
  (ITEM.id=ITEM_TAG.id_item AND TAG.id=ITEM_TAG.id_dtag AND TAG.url='tag2')
...
AND
  (ITEM.id=ITEM_TAG.id_item AND TAG.id=ITEM_TAG.id_dtag AND TAG.url='tagn')
```

This one works :

```
SELECT 
  ITEM.id AS 'item_id',
  ITEM.title AS 'item_title',
  ITEM.content AS 'item_content'
FROM ITEM
  INNER JOIN TAG TAG1
   ON TAG1.url='tag1'
  INNER JOIN ITEM_TAG ITEM_TAG1
   ON ITEM_TAG1.id_item=ITEM.id AND ITEM_TAG1.id_tag=TAG1.id
  INNER JOIN TAG TAG2
   ON TAG2.url='tag2'
  INNER JOIN ITEM_TAG ITEM_TAG2
   ON ITEM_TAG2.id_item=ITEM.id AND ITEM_TAG2.id_tag=TAG2.id
  ...
  INNER JOIN TAG TAGn
   ON TAG2.url='tagn'
  INNER JOIN ITEM_TAG ITEM_TAGn
   ON ITEM_TAGn.id_item=ITEM.id AND ITEM_TAGn.id_tag=TAGn.id
```

At this point, is there a better way to do that, than those `INNER JOIN` and `ON` ?

**2. Get the related tags for other tags**

Here I would like to get the list of tags and the number of items that match other tags.

For example, let's imagine the following fixtures :

```
    ITEM_TAG             TAG
id_item | id_tag       id | url
1       | 1            1  | tag1
1       | 2            2  | tag2
1       | 3            3  | tag3
1       | 4            4  | tag4
2       | 1
2       | 2
2       | 3
3       | 1
3       | 2
```

Always with the following search `mydomain/items/tag1+tag2/`.

I wish to display the **other tags** with a relation with some items (if those relations exist).

I'm sorry to say that I have no idea on how to make a request that will output the following :

```
    TAG
url    count(id_item)
tag3 | 2
tag4 | 1
```

How to get this result ?

**Edit**

I tried the following wich seems to work :

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(id_item) AS 'nb_item', 
  TAG.url AS 'tag_url'
FROM ITEM_TAG, TAG
WHERE 
 url NOT IN ('tag1','tag2')
 AND id_item IN 
 (
   SELECT id_item FROM ITEM_TAG, TAG 
   WHERE url IN ('tag1','tag2') AND id_tag=id
 )
 AND id_tag=id
GROUP BY TAG.id ORDER BY nb_item DESC
```

Any idea or advise to optimize this will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: The first one can be done with the subquery ....... Select id,title,content from Item where id in(select id_item from Item_tag where id_tag in(select id from Tag where url in('tag1','tag2')))

Comment: Is this a better way than Andomar answer ?

Comment: I think joining will take a lot of time and space than this..... that's why I have given the solution with subquery

Comment: @Jatin Khurana Ok, thanks, have you got a solution for the second one ? Then, please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Get the items by tags**

```
select  i.id
,       i.title
,       i.content
from    item i
join    item_tag it
on      i.id = it.id_item
join    tag t
on      t.id = it.id_tag
where   t.url in ('tag1', 'tag2')
```

**2. Get the related tags for other tags**

```
select  t2.url
,       count(it2.id_item)
from    tag t1 -- this tag
join    item_tag it1
on      t1.id = it.id_tag
join    item_tag it2 -- other tag for same item
on      it2.item_id = it1.item_id
join    tag t2
on      t2.id = it2.id_tag
where   t1.url in ('tag1', 'tag2')
        and t2.url not in ('tag1', 'tag2')
group by
        t2.url
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But after testing the 2nd solution, it outputs only one other tag (by my example, it may output : "tag3" and "tag4").

Comment: See my edit, it works, based on your `NOT IN`, if you see a better solution le me know. +1 anyway